# How to use bootstrap datetime picker with custom HTML form in Google sheets?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, momentjs

I have Google sheet. I made custom HTML form with bootstrap datetime picker

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" integrity="sha256-FAOaXTpl90/K8cXmSdsskbQN3nKYulhCpPbcFzGTWKI=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <form>           
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
      </script>      
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Подтвердить</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha256-4HOrwHz9ACPZBxAav7mYYlbeMiAL0h6+lZ36cLNpR+E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-bqVeqGdJ7h/lYPq6xrPv/YGzMEb6dNxlfiTUHSgRCp8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.ru.min.js" integrity="sha256-iGDUwn2IPSzlnLlVeCe3M4ZIxQxjUoDYdEO6oBZw/Go=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

  </body>
</html>
```

I included libraries which was required. But it does not work for me. 
Unfortunately, I do not understand where I'm wrong. 
How to fix it?

Comment: You are missing import `<script>` for `datetimepicker`. `bootstrap-datepicker.ru.min.js` is only the localization for the plugin, moreover datetimepicker != datepicker.

Comment: When you click Run code snippet here, an error occurs because the code which references jQuery (`$`) is included before jQuery is.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following script after `</body>` in your Html. It ensures the code to run after the document loaded and being ready for binding datepicker to the  element. Besides, it is `.datepicker()` but not `.datetimepicker()`.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();
    })
  </script>
```

If you just want to build a DATE picker, bootstrap-datepicker is NOT necessary. Just use bootstrap built-in input type:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control">
```